# How to stop images in apple mail signature is being magnified

Tags: email, graphics, signature

I'm trying to add a logo in apple mail signature.
The image is a small PNG. When I added to the the signature in preferences, it's fine. But when I visit that signature again (or) create a mail with that signature, the image magnifies while the retina resolution is gone. How to I stop it?

[image: in preferences]
[image: actual email]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a DPI limitation in Mail for images in signatures.

[This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4904835?tstart=0) on Apple's discussion forums details what one user did to resolve the issue:

> I had 2 things too big in my image settings; the canvas size (which was 14cm long!) and the DPI (which was 300dpi) I have since changed to approx 8cm long and 100DPI and it now displays the logo in the signature without increasing the size of it to fit the size of the window.

I would recommend instead converting to 72 DPI, which is a standard; based on comments I've read elsewhere I believe it's converting higher DPI images to 72 DPI, which in turn causes the image size on-screen to increase.

Comment: 72 DPI makes sense, but it usually leads to soft edges in your signature image in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I found by experimentation that the image was being being displayed at twice the size of the original 72dpi image. I set the source image to 144 dpi and doubled the dimensions of the image. The result appears crisp in my email.